# How to enable reference resolution on custom functions in PhpStorm

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, code-completion

PhpStorm has some nice file path completion for basic PHP functions like `require` and `include`.

[image]

Is it somehow possible to enable that completion for custom functions too? Maybe via PHPDoc?

Comment: You want PHPStorm to complete paths in function argument for functions that require paths?  eg: say this custom function `emptyDirectory($path)`.  You want, when you open the parentheses, PHPStorm to start suggesting paths?

Comment: You got the point! I want to activate that helper for arguments which are meant to be a file.

Comment: Don't get excited too soon. I have no idea how to do this. Sorry

Comment: Check out this plugin https://github.com/King2500/PhpAdvancedAutoComplete It extends the set of functions with such autocompletion (not only filepaths, but also dates and other smarty things). You can propose to the author your idea with PHPDoc parameters ))